# How do you make an array of lists in clojure?

Tags: clojure

So I'm working on a compiler lexer, and I am defining the transition table with 
        `(make-array rows)`
where rows is a list of list of lists.

However, I'm running into memory issues creating a tall nested list of 800 * 127 * '() rows, and then converting it back to array.

Is there a way to create an empty 2d-array, and then dynamically set its cells with lists? List sizes of each cells would not be same.

Comment: I assume you don't have the memory available to use vectors? Using an array means you lose the benefits of the STM system.

Comment: I bet the array is sparse - most entries are void. Since nearly all states will have at least one exit transition, you can represent the array compactly by an array of lists, tagging each entry with its target id. This is incredibly slow to access - you would use a map in real life, but the list should get you under the memory bar.

Comment: Yep! I ended up doing that. And it worked like a charm. Slower, but at least it compiled, and ran.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't actually *need* to initialize each value to `clojure.lang.PersistentList$EmptyList` (aka `'()`), this can be as simple as:

```
(make-array clojure.lang.PersistentList 800 127)
```

...that said, I don't particularly recommend it. Is there a reason you can't use a vector of vectors?

Comment: That works. However, I am still running out of memory after doing my assignments for each cell. I'll be trying out a different technique now. But, thanks.

The reason I can't use vectors is quite stupid. This is part of a homework assignment, and according to the spec we are supposed to create a clojure array, returned by (make-array) or (to-array-2d), from a transition function of NFA. We are not allowed to use vectors.